# Internal Link redirection to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

There are three internal links as below.

```
<a  href="#modal" >Link1</a>
```

`<a  href="#modal" >Link2</a>` 
`<a href="#modal" >Link3</a>`

When I click Link1 it must redirect to Page1.html
When I click Link2 it must redirect to Page2.html
When I click Link3 it must redirect to Page3.html

The three links are using same internal link which is used for Login popup.

Once the login complete the link should redirect to corresponding page.

As I am using OpenID for login and redirecting

```
$openid->returnUrl = 'http://localhost:60325/page1.html' ;
```

The problem is that when I click on link1 link2 and link3 its redirecting to page1.html.

please help me with a code to identify which internal link clicked.

Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: a code to identify which internal link clicked.

Comment: who does the redirection? javascript or PHP?

Comment: @Ghost,PHP will be preferred.The problem is that how can we notice php which internal link is clicked as three internal links has same name

Comment: @KiranNath when you click the link, does it redirect immediately, or the popup login will open first, then after that, redirect? your question is too broad and the details are not complete/not enough context

Comment: @Ghost, When clicking on the link the popup login opens.After successful login it redirects to corresponding pages as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @KiranNath so this is actually a form? could you post a markup, and the PHP that actually handles that submission

Comment: Do you not have control over these generated links?

Comment: @Ghost it a openid google authentication.When I click on the internal link popup login will appears that prompt Connect with Google.When we click on the Connect with Google link it redirects to page1.php

<a href="<?php echo $openid->authUrl() ?>" class="social_box google">
      <span class="iccon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="iccon_title">Connect with Google</span>
     </a>
---------------------------------------------

 $openid->returnUrl = 'http://localhost:60325/page1.php' ;

Comment: @KiranNath so the trick here is that you hardcode the return url before the login popup hasn't even made yet, so after google said/responded and says ok on authentication, then it will use `$openid->returnUrl` which you have set from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

if you post the form without ajax you can do in php

```
  header("Location: http://yoursite.bb");
```

if your form are by procesing by ajax you need to do a redirect after you get a positive or negative response.

Something like:

```
  document.location.href = 'http://yoursite.bb';
```

PS: to sort out the problem and describe the specific exhibitions code that we understand you

I personally do not understand, you need a redirect, or determine which link was clicked?

Maybe for your link you need to give them the different links and that they refer to the same place and they do not have a different id's or classes

Comment: Let me explain.

When I click on the internal link [Link1].The page should redirect to page1.

When I click on the internal link [Link2].The page should redirect to page2.

When I click on the internal link [Link3].The page should redirect to page3.

Comment: how the server or client can redirect you if over your link's have a href="#modal" and havent id or class, I'm write you simple examples if you _POST_ the form you can give a **header** after your code are procesing or redirect with javascript after you get the response but your form must have **hidden input** with page name or url must have a different id (example: **<a href="#modal" id="page1">Link1</a>**)

Answer (score 0):

A more secure way to handle authentication is to do it on the server-side, never do it on the client-side, you can do it easily with PHP or another server-side language and then redirect with a HTTP based request.

example on PHP:

```
// On the prev urls 
@session_start();
$_SESSION['prev_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// This will provide the internal link for example /index.html
```

and on the authentication file put this:

```
//after authentication 
@session_start();
$prev_url = $_SESSION['prev_url']; // pass the saved value
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."/".$prev_url); // redirect
```

Comment: Yes that's great.But how can we notice the php which internal link is clicked as three internal links have same name

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$_GET` method and add which location you want to go to like this...

```
<a href="login.php?redirect=page1">link1</a>
<a href="login.php?redirect=page2">link2</a>
<a href="login.php?redirect=page3">link3</a>
```

and then use a switch statement within your login validation like this...

```
$location = $_GET['redirect'];

function getRedirect ($option){
    switch($option){
        case page1:
            header("location: page1.php");
            break;
        case page2:
            header("location: page2.php");
            break;
        case page3:
            header("location: page3.php");
            break;
    }
}

$redirect = getRedirect($location);

if(10 > 1){
    $redirect;
}
```

with this depending on which link is clicked originally the end link the login validation success sends the user to changes

(i put the success true by using `10 > 1` for you to be able to test the code quickly and see how it works)